# How to render multiple teaser and one full view mode (of the active teaser) on the same page?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to do the following:

- Show the teasers off all the posts (content type: application_formulier) in a horizontal scroll, this works using the "simplyscroll module and is already finished (black part of the img.)
- Show the full view mode of the selected teaser (clicked the read more link) belowe the teasers (red part of the picture). (This is what i can't get to work. What is shown on the img is just to explain my goal.)
- When clikking on the "read more" link to show the full view mode you need to stay on the same page, not go to the nodes personal page.

The second bullet is what i need to make but i have no idee on how to do this.

Could somebady plz point me in the right direction on how to do this?

What i want:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what's the problem? You can have views block with nodes, for example, and node in content. And there is no easyscroll module on drupal.org

Comment: Hey molot, Sorry about that i got the module name wrong. I eddited my question. Could you explain a bit more what you mean by "views block with nodes" and "node in content" plz.

Comment: In a theme, on a node's own page, there is usually a div where node's content is rendered, called content. Views-generated blocks (and that's what SimplyScroll seems to operate on) should not interfere in any way, if they are in regions like page_top or left_sidebar. That's why I can't understand what's wrong with your setup.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong atm, its just that the red part isnt made yet. And i have no clue on how to do it... What i tried to do is add a new view to the footer of the one where the teasers are displayed (thats whats on the img) but that doesnt gives me what i need.  What i need is to only show the full view of one teaser. (the one where someone clicked on the read more link). If this still isnt clear plz tell me and ill try to explain a bit more.